# Is css-sprite a good technique?

Tags: css, css-sprites

1. is css-sprite good technique? I read about its pros at http://spriteme.org/ and have also I seen a lot of questions about css sprites here in stackoverflow.
2. What are its cons?
3. Will it work in all browsers as claimed in their site?

Comment: I want to add a question: is it difficult to implement and how about maintainability?

Comment: Implementing and maintaining will be harder as compared to normal images since you have to calculate the offsets manually. But I think there are CSS sprite generators to reduce the overhead of doing this manually.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, it is a good technique.

You can reduce the number of HTTP requests and it is a page optimization technique.

The first rule in

[Best Practices for Speeding Websites by Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)

is

Minimize HTTP Requests

> 80% of the end-user response time is
>   spent on the front-end. Most of this
>   time is tied up in downloading all the
>   components in the page: images,
>   stylesheets, scripts, Flash, etc.
>   Reducing the number of components in
>   turn reduces the number of HTTP
>   requests required to render the page.
>   This is the key to faster pages.
>
> **CSS Sprites** are the preferred method
>   for reducing the number of image
>   requests. Combine your background
>   images into a single image and use the
>   CSS background-image and
>   background-position properties to
>   display the desired image segment.
>
> One way to reduce the number of
>   components in the page is to simplify
>   the page's design. But is there a way
>   to build pages with richer content
>   while also achieving fast response
>   times? Here are some techniques for
>   reducing the number of HTTP requests,
>   while still supporting rich page
>   designs.

When you need to change the dimensions of the images inside the sprite then you have to recalculate the offsets for the images. But I don't think this is a huge burden.

It is supported by almost all modern browsers.

This is also a good article on CSS sprites

**[CSS Sprites: What They Are, Why They’re Cool, and How To Use Them](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)**

Answer (score 4):

It worked for IE 6 Safari Opera 8+ and FF2+.
You should read this:

[Gif Compression](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/graphics/gifs_compression_algorithm.php3)

It explains how GIF (and other image files) are compressed.
For example displaying the same data in "rows" instead of "columns" reduces the space usage dramatically.

Furthermore you preload all images and there is no delay if you swap images.

Another plus is that you can use one sprite for a "red" design and another sprite for a "blue" design.

However there is one *disadvantage*:

Most of the browsers cache the image sprites.
So you might running into troubles when it comes to updating the sprite.

Comment: Caching will be a problem with any image and not just image sprites.

Comment: You could change the filename (version it?) to defeat that caching problem.

Comment: But within some browser images are reloaded on refresh but backbround images are not. A simple way to get arround this is using url(my_sprite.png?v1). So you don't have to rename the file and the browser is forced to reload it.

Answer (score 2):

Its a great technique, but you have to be real carefull as how you do it so it works correctly in every browser.

It can be done and is a good optimizing tip, but as always, pay attention as how it works in IE, Firefox and Chrome while you are doing it.

The cons are that it can't be used always, and you have to stick to the least common denominator for cross browser css support.

Answer (score 2):

Done right, it should work fine in all browsers (even IE6).

The biggest con I can think of is that if you have too many images in one sprite, and need to change the dimensions for just one of them, it can cause you to have to change a lot of CSS (since the offsets for other images will probably change as well)

Comment: Yea its harder to maintain. For something that doesnt change a lot its good.

Answer (score 2):

One downside i've run into is that CSS sprites don't seem to print properly in many browsers

Answer (score 0):

Of course, because it saves lot of http request, that very important for your website loading time.

Check out this page:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-sprites.php

It has a great explanation and everything you need to know about CSS Sprite.