# Avoid flickering on mouse over

Tags: css

I have a simple link in a menu

```
<a id="Home" href="Amico-Bio-Home-Page"></a>
```

to which i apply the following style

```
#Home{
background-image:url(../Images/Menu/home.png);
```

background-repeat:no-repeat;
 border:none;
 display:block;
 height:70px;
 text-decoration:none;
 width:78px;
 float:left;
 padding:0 7px;
}

```
#Home:hover {
 background-image: url(../Images/Menu/homeOn.png);
}
```

when i go over the link the images are swapped.

while swapping the images the link disappear for an instant.

Do you know any way to avoid it?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sprites:
[Is css-sprite a good technique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477332/is-css-sprite-a-good-technique)

Comment: Exactly.  The "flicker" occurs because the browser has to go download the second image.

Answer (score 2):

You should use image sprite sheets.  For a detailed tutorial on them look here: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest avoiding images altogether and use CSS to style your links. You can accomplish a lot with CSS3 background and border gradients, text-shadows, and more. Check out: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-gradient-buttons/  and http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/12-excellent-css3-button-and-menu-techniques for inspiration and code.

Answer (score 0):

html part

```
<a><img src="homeOn.png" alt="" width="" height="" /></a>
```

css part

```
a {height:px;width:px;background-image:url(home.png)}
a:hover img {visibility:hidden}
```

added bonus no more [IE6 flicker](http://fivesevensix.com/studies/ie6flicker/)